# ERROR: '/lib/servlet-api.jar' not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to run a Java EE project on my Eclipse(Luna). but I'm getting this "ERROR: '/lib/servlet-api.jar' not found!" it says also that

> Possible reasons may include one or more of the following:
>   - The Tomcat 'CATALINA_HOME' environment variable was not set properly
>   - Tomcat was not installed properly

however I have already set 'CATALINA_HOME' as "/usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.55" under the run configurations.
I still don't get what's wrong with the definition of my CATALINA_HOME, should I set it differently?

Comment: did you try setting `CLASSPATH` as mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654122/processing-java-servlet-javax-servlet-package-not-found

Comment: Also, try using the `Server plugin` to add tomcat server runtime to manage all such settings cleanly. Plugin can be found from marketplace, or alternatively try this link: http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html#A3

Comment: I finally got the reason, it was caused by some extra jars that i added manually to the build path, removing those jars solved the problem. Thanks for your help.