# Using Processing as a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, processing

This topic has been discussed before here ([Using Processing on a server to create images behind the scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889881/using-processing-on-a-server-to-create-images-behind-the-scenes), and [Rendering images with Processing.org on Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427105/rendering-images-with-processing-org-on-java-servlet)) and a very promising solution proposed by @George Bashi.  But I have encountered difficulties regarding its implementation.  If I write a .java file with Processing syntax, with which libraries would I need to compile with it to preserve Processing structure?  When I compile such a file with processing.core.jar, servlet-api.jar, javac calls errors on all the Processing-unique syntax.  Trying to avoid re-writing a Processing program into standard Java, how would one compile a Processing .java file into a .class that is usable as a Java servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I feel dumb.  Eclipse with Web Tools and http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-java-servlets-with-eclipse.html saved the day.  Learn something new every day.